# Selection dropdown items not loading when I refresh the page

Tags: php, html, mysql, session

So I'm using this code to population a dropdown:

```
<select id="sel" name="char">
  <?php
    $s = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `characters` WHERE `accountid`='" . $_SESSION['id'] . "' ORDER BY `id` ASC") or die($mysqli->error);
        while ($c = $s->fetch_array()) {
            echo '<option value="' . $c['id'] . '">' . $c['name'] . '</option>';
        }
  ?>
</select>
```

This works initially, but when I refresh the page the options do not show up anymore. Its just a blank dropdown. Was wondering what the reason for this is? I've made sure session_start(); is on this page as well. Any suggestions?

Comment: If it works on the first time then fails on subsequent refreshes, you should check if `$_SESSION['id']` is getting changes in any way. Do a `var_dump($_SESSION);` at the beginning of this page to see if it's what you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks! This helped! So it seems like $_session['id'] was being given a new value when I refresh the page. This is very strange because I'm pretty sure I never purposefully assigned it a new value. EDIT: Upon further inspection i found out that if I don't submit the form and refresh the data stays there, but if I submit the form (using ajax so the page is not refreshed) then manually refresh the page after getting a response back the drop down will appear empty.

Comment: can you show the code please where you are storing:$_SESSION['id']

Comment: `if($cpA['password'] == sha1($cpP) || $cpA['password'] == hash('sha512',$cpP.$cpA['salt'])) {
    $sanitizename = sql_sanitize($cpA['name']);
    $sanitizepass = sql_sanitize($cpA['password']);
    $selectQ = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE name='".$sanitizename."' AND password='".$sanitizepass."'") or die($mysqli->error);
    $selectF = $selectQ->fetch_array();`
   ** $_SESSION['id'] = $selectF['id'];** `
    $_SESSION['name'] = $selectF['name']; `